# Deploy to production MEAN app (Angular2)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx, mean-stack

I am trying deploy my first angular 2 app with mongodb/express on my own server (debian with nginx )

I have installed everything like nginx, mongo, node, build-essentials, pm2 etc

I am starting my server.js by pm2 start server.js -x -- --prod

my server.js file

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use(expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }).unless({ path: ['/users/authenticate', '/users/register'] }));

// routes
app.use('/users', require('./controllers/users.controller'));

// start server
app.listen(3008, function() {
    console.log('server na porcie 3008!')
});
```

This is my config.json

```
{
    "connectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb",
    "apiUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:3008",
    "secret": "testing testing"
}
```

My front-end is in angular2/4 I also used ng build --prod for create my dist directory. My path to dist on server is /srv/mydomain/dist

And my server part is inside /srv/mydomain/server

Whem I am open my app I see my front end with login

After typing login and password console shows errors

> OPTIONS http://localhost:4000/users/authenticate net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>   XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:4000/users/authenticate".

I don't know why is 4000 instead of 3008?

There is my nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # Web
    root /srv/myapp/dist;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # Api
    location /srv/myapp/server {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3008;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Edit

This is my authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        //console.log(this.config.apiUrl);
        return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + '/users/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let user = response.json();
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }
            });
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are making this authenticate request?

Comment: @echonax Added at the end of my question

Comment: Can you console.log the apiUrl? I'll edit your question with a comment.

Comment: What does my edit print?

Comment: @echonax I am checking give me a moment I must build it

Comment: @echonax I don't know why but now I can't access to my front and I am getting 403 Forbidden

Comment: Did the console.log log something?

Comment: no I also started app just by ng server and all works fine on localhost but still nothing in console.log

Comment: So you are calling your login() method and the console doesn't logs? You commented in that line right?

Comment: I get someting: apiUrl log: http://127.0.0.1:3008

i did console.log('apiUrl log',this.config.apiUrl);

but it's in dev mode